# Trouble reading in staggered free-format data

Tags: sas

I need to read this in using some pointer locations and will trim the parenthesis out later. For the time-being, I'm having some trouble with the logic tree which tells the program to move to different levels and apply input accordingly.

Here's a little sample of the data file:

Levels 1- 6 start at positions 1, 10, 19, 28, 37, and 46, respectively.
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NZnahMYU9uMUZmeWQ3eUI2ZnM/view?usp=sharing)
Here's my code:

```
Data peg;
    infile Pegasus  dlm= ' ';
    length Job_Title $23 Employee_Name $20;
    input Level  & @;
    if Level="(Level1)" then
    input @10 Job_Title & @34 Employee_Name & @108 Salary dollar8. ;
    else if Level="(Level2)" then
    input @19 Job_Title & Employee_Name & @108 Salary dollar8. ;
    else if Level="(Level3)" then
    input @28 Job_Title & Employee_Name & @108 Salary dollar8. ;
    else if Level="(Level4)" then
    input @37 Job_Title & Employee_Name & @108 Salary dollar8. ;
    else if Level="(Level5)" then
    input @46 Job_Title & Employee_Name & @108 Salary dollar8. ;
    else if Level="(Level6)" then
    input @55 Job_Title & Employee_Name & @108 Salary dollar10.;
run;
```

[image] This is what happens when I run the above code.

Comment: Please post some sample data as text.

Comment: No one can run your code based on an image. I would suggest reading each row as long string and parsing out after. The SCAN() function will be helpful.

Comment: Level 3 doesn't work because it's IF/THEN. Once a condition is true the others are not tested, so if your second condition is true you're done the if/then step and never reach your third step.

Comment: I added a link to the data. Reeza, how could I adjust the logic? I tried using separate if/then/else clauses based on the value of Level and it had a similar issue to this code.

Comment: Define `LEVEL` as character in your `LENGTH` statement before trying to read it. Or at least add `$` to the `INPUT` statement so that SAS knows to read character string instead of a number.

Comment: Tom, your suggestion and the missover statement made it happen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If missover changed the result then make sure that you do not have missing SALARY values. I always use TRUNCOVER instead of missover because it never throws away data when you try to read past the end of the line with a formatted style input statement, such as `salary dollar8.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would probably work if you remove the DSD option on the INFILE statement and removed the format from the first INPUT and added a trailing @ to hold the line for the conditional generated INPUT. The Employee_Name value will have () around it, but you could remove those later.

```
infile Pegasus truncover ;
length Level $8 Job_Title $23 Employee_Name $20 Salary 8;
input Level @;
```

But you don't need  the conditionally generated INPUT statements with hard coded column locations. You should just ignore the indentation. Read in the string and parse out the values based on the locations of the `()`.

That data looks clean enough that you could just read the fields directly using `&` modifier if you tell SAS to treat `()` as additional delimiters in addition to the normal default delimiter of the space character.

```
data want;
  infile cards dlm=' ()' truncover;
  length Level $8 Job_Title $23 Employee_Name $20 Salary 8 ;
  informat salary comma. ;
  format salary dollar12. ;
  input ( Level -- Salary) (&) ;
cards;                                                                                                                                  
(Level1) Chief Executive Officer  (Anthony Miller )                                                        $433,800                     
         (Level2) Chief Sales Officer  (Harry Highpoint )                                                  $243,190                     
                  (Level3) Vice President  (Henri Le Bleu )                                                $194,885                     
                           (Level4) Director  (Reginald Steiber )                                          $156,065                     
                                    (Level5) Sales Manager  (Dennis Lansberry )                             $84,260                     
                                             (Level6) Sales Rep. I  (Saunders Briggi )                      $26,335                     
;
```

Here is what the first few values look like:
[image]

If that doesn't work then read it into a variable and use `SCAN()` to parse it.

```
  input string $107. salary;
  level = scan(string,1,'()');
  job_title = left(scan(string,2,'()'));
  employee_name = left(scan(string,3,'()'));
```

Comment: That does simplify things quite a bit. If I were to try to master the indentations and/or if/then/else logic for this based on level, how would I do it? I would like to understand how to do that as well, ideally.

Comment: Your code would probably work if you remove the DSD option on the INFILE statement. Removed the format from the first INPUT and added a trailing @.

Comment: It almost works... on the bright side, it does access all the observations. However, it only accesses the names for level 1. The others are kind of janky. I attached a picture above.